# Baking a displacement map with Blender 2.8 and Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking, baking, displacement

I want to achieve a greyscale displacement map, like this one:

[image: displacement example]

I have a model and another model which has been modified using a displacement modifier, now I want to bake that displacement into the uv map.

Following [this awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw) I was able to generate a normal map, however I see no displacement in the bake type selection

[image]

How do I make a displacement map instead?

Here is the blendfile if anyone wants to take a look.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IrQmUGCSRCOfJQmsxSaZAlCw4XE49YZi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sadly there is no built-in method to bake displacement maps in Blender **yet**. However, there is a lot of talk going on within the Dev community about it lately, so this might change in the future. Right now, the only workaround I can offer, is described in a video tutorial by CGCookie: ["Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY). It can be done with Blender 2.79 and Blender 2.80, but for both it works only in experimental mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info, sadly my setup is different from the one in the video, I have two models where one is "bigger" than the other, and they share the same vertices/faces. I don't have a node setup like that